# Samba PDC share slow with LDAP backend

Tags: linux, performance, ldap, samba, sles

**The scenario**

I have a SUSE SLES 11.1 SP1 machine as Samba master PDC with LDAP backend. In one share there are Database files for a Client-Server application.
I log XP and Windows 7 machines to the local domain (example.local), the login is a little slow but works. 
In the client computers have an executable which opens, reads and writes the database files from the server share.

**The Problem**

When running Samba with LDAP password backend the client application runs VERY SLOW with a maximum transfer rate of 2500 MBit per second.
If disable LDAP the client app speed increases 20x, with transfer rate of >50Mbit/sec and running smoothly.

I'm doing test with just two users and two machines, so concurrency, or LDAP size shouldn't be the problem here.

**The suspect**

LDAP, Smb.conf [global] section configuration.

**The Question**

What can I do? I've googled a lot, but still have no answer.

Slow smb.conf WITH LDAP

```
[global]
        workgroup = zmartsoft.local
        passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://127.0.0.1
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        printcap cache time = 750
        cups options = raw
        map to guest = Bad User
        logon path = \\%L\profiles\.msprofile
        logon home = \\%L\%U\.9xprofile
        logon drive = P:
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd  -c Machine -d /var/lib/nobody -s
 /bin/false %m$
        domain logons = Yes
        domain master = Yes
        local master = Yes
        netbios name = server
        os level = 65
        preferred master = Yes
        security = user
        wins support = Yes
        idmap backend = ldap:ldap://127.0.0.1
        ldap admin dn = cn=Administrator,dc=zmartsoft,dc=local
        ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
        ldap idmap suffix = ou=Idmap
        ldap machine suffix = ou=Machines
        ldap passwd sync = Yes
        ldap ssl = Off
        ldap suffix = dc=zmartsoft,dc=local
        ldap user suffix = ou=Users
```

Comment: You can't just share database files like this, you will end up with corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after months of look everywhere I read this article 
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/samba_reference_guide/24_locking_08.html

and started to play with oplock values.
The Windows application did a lot of read write operations, each time changing permissions, when disabling the oplocks things started to going better.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check to see if your name-service cache daemon (nscd) is working right. The slowdown you're seeing may be related to username->UID lookups. You might get some speedups by mounting that volume with `noatime` as that'll prevent the lookups from happening as often. But those values should be cached for a certain period.

Comment: I just noticed that the share only run fast if the password backend in [global] is set to smbpass. Either ldap and tdbsam are slow

Comment: mounting noatime was helpful into gaining some performance.